# How to create multi page pdf preview using html and css and java script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to create a preview of a pdf document and display it as a card using HTML/CSS. This is very similar to how Google drive displays previews of the docs on their home page. I have already designed a card using HTML and CSS and also rendered the png version of the first page of the HTML. I am wondering how to add a way to preview multiple pages by some kind of interaction in the card (like a carousel).

I have already created a card and preview of the HTML - here's the code.

```
    <div class="doc-thumbnail">
   <div class="doc-thumbnail-preview">

   </div>

   <div class="doc-thumbnail-info">
     <div class="file-info"> 
       <div>
         <h3 class="title">Some Title</h3>
       </div>
       <div>
         <p class="description">Some long description </p>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class='doc-view-stats'>
       <p>
         Last viewed: Today
       </p> 
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.doc-thumbnail-container {
   max-width: 100%;
   width:100%;
   margin: 4%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   
}

.doc-thumbnail {
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #ece2e2;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-around;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
   height: 400px;

   
}



.doc-thumbnail-preview {
    color: #fff;
   padding: 10px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
   max-width: 250px;
   height:100%;
   margin-top: 10px;
   background-image:url("https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_200,h_300,c_fill/sample_document.docx.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center top;
   pointer-events: none;
}

.doc-thumbnail-info {
   border-top: 1px solid var(--card-border-color) ;
   background-color: var(--card-background-color);
   color: var(--text-color);
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-content: center;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 3px;
    position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   pointer-events: none;

}
```

Here's a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/stevemnunathan/ko7ntpjg/